# How to retrieve beacon diagnostics from the proximity api?

Tags: eddystone, google-beacon-platform, google-nearby, proximityapi

I have registered a few beacons on the proximity api. According to the documentation if I am using nearby api the telemetry information are submitted by the nearby api itself. Also in the documentation for monitoring beacons mention that I can list beacon diagnostics information using the google oauth playground. Unfortunately when I try to list the beacon diagnostics all I get back is the beacon name. Any help regarding this would be great!

Comment: Do you know that your beacon is actually transmitting telemetry data?  You can check this by using the free [Locate app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) and tapping on the detail view of the Eddystone transmission.  If telemetry is transmitting, it should eventually show up on the detail view.

Comment: It is transmitting telemetry data. and I intend to retrieve the telemetry using the proximity api!

Comment: I have also encountered zero success getting diagnostic data to appear. At a minimum, some direction on how to even begin to debug the situation would be helpful @MarcWan

Comment: @Devunwired Have you had any luck with retrieving diagnostics information?

Answer (score 2):

At this point in time, the Diagnostics API only can return two possible things:

1. Expected battery life.
2. An alert if:

   1. The battery is about to run out.
   2. The beacon has been reported in a location different than its registered location.

Battery information requires that the beacon be broadcasting [telemetry frames](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-tlm), and that people scanning for beacons have seen these TLM frames.

And yet, even with these conditions both being true, it takes a while for the Proximity Beacon API backend to decide it's seen enough data points to be able to start reporting these things. Given the high number of variables that go into the analysis, it's hard to come up with a good idea of the exact number of sightings required.

There has been talk of making the Diagnostics API a bit more … communicative, but nothing concrete yet. I'll update this question when I learn more.

Comment: is there any update on the Diagnostics Api? Also another doubt I had was, would nearby messages api send telemetry information to the cloud everytime it finds a beacon/message?